# jquery filter a select which its options contains some string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider below select

```
<select id="phone_line" name="phone_line">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="BB-11">Line 1</option>
    <option value="AA-22">Line 2</option>
    <option value="AA-33">Line 3</option>
    <option value="BB-44">Line 4</option>
</select>
```

If i want to filter the options and remove line with value `BB-44` I can do it as:

```
$('#phone_line option').filter(' option[value="BB-44"] ').remove();
```

If I want to remove lines which their values **starts** with `AA` ? I can do it with each as below:

```
$("#phone_line > option").each(function () {    
    if (this.value.substring(0, 2) === 'AA') {
        $("#phone_line option[value='" + this.value +"']").remove();
    }
});
```

But can I do it with filters ( in one line ?! ). Code At:

http://jsfiddle.net/mpp4emd1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using attribute `starts with` selector will do it

```
$('#phone_line option[value^="AA"]').remove();
```

Reference: **[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ffouh241/)**</kbd>

For more complex filtering use `filter(function)`

```
$("#phone_line > option").filter(function () {    
   return this.value.substring(0, 2) === 'AA';
}).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks the filter with sub string can do more for complex value selection.

Comment: Yes definitely. There are other attribute selectors but for absolute control this is best

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `$("#phone_line option").filter('[value^="AA"]').remove();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
$('#phone_line').find('option[value^="AA"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="phone_line" name="phone_line">
    <option value="">select phone line...</option>
    <option value="BB-11">Line 1</option>
    <option value="AA-22">Line 2</option>
    <option value="AA-33">Line 3</option>
    <option value="BB-44">Line 4</option>
</select>
```

`$('#phone_line').find('option[value^="AA"]')` this returns a collection and you don't need to have `.filter()` to remove the options which starts/contains the value `AA`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the trick:

```
$('#phone_line option').filter(' option[value^="AA"] ').remove();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/mpp4emd1)